# Trying to write my own loss function on Tensorflow high level API

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to come up with my own loss function while dealing with reinforcement learning problem.(Open Ai's 'CartPole-v0' game.)

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(32,))  # Returns a placeholder tensor

# A layer instance is callable on a tensor, and returns a tensor.
x = keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
output = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)

# Instantiate the model given inputs and outputs.
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)

chosen_action = tf.argmax(output,1)

#The next six lines establish the training proceedure. We feed the reward and chosen action into the network
#to compute the loss, and use it to update the network.
reward_holder = tf.placeholder(shape=[None],dtype=tf.float32)
action_holder = tf.placeholder(shape=[None],dtype=tf.int32)

#here, basically I am finding the final decisioned outputs of neural network.
indexes = tf.range(0, tf.shape(output)[0]) * tf.shape(output)[1] + action_holder
responsible_outputs = tf.gather(tf.reshape(output, [-1]), indexes)

#this is the loss function that I want to use
myloss = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(responsible_outputs)*reward_holder)
```

Everything is cool until here.

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(), 
              loss=myloss,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

When I do this, I get this error;

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-2b1cccfa091b> in <module>()
      1 model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(), 
      2               loss=myloss,
----> 3               metrics=['accuracy'])

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, loss_weights, sample_weight_mode, weighted_metrics, target_tensors, **kwargs)
    172             `optimizer`, `loss`, `metrics` or `sample_weight_mode`.
    173     """
--> 174     loss = loss or {}
    175     if context.executing_eagerly() and not isinstance(
    176         optimizer, (tf_optimizer_module.Optimizer, optimizers.TFOptimizer)):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in __bool__(self)
    663       `TypeError`.
    664     """

--> 665     raise TypeError("Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. "
    666                     "Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a "
    667                     "tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as "

TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you did not specify a learning rate in your AdamOptimizer.  The adam optimizer uses an adaptive momentum gradient descent algorithm to update the weights and biases in your neural network.  The speed of update depends on the specified learning rate.

A correction would be: optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(**learning_rate**)